# Летающие по сайту птички... понимаю что звучит как бред

Tags: javascript

Задача: есть сайт, нужно чтобы по сайту, по определенной траектории, периодически пролетали птички.
Вопрос:
 1. Птичек лучше сделать в анимированном gif или во флеш?
 2. Как это вообще реализовать? В скриптах разбираюсь весьма посредственно, выучить какойто язык сейчас просто не успею, вобщем нужен удар под попу в нужном направлении.

Заранее спасибо тем кто отнесется с пониманием и не пошлет в джунгли :)

Comment: делаем в gif нужную птицу, ставим все это в div  с абсолютным позиционированием. Заодно, скачайте любой скрипт, который добавляет "снег"

Comment: Вариант летающих птиц на HTML5: [thewildernessdowntown.com][1].


  [1]: http://thewildernessdowntown.com/

Comment: хм... красиво... а как их себе на сайт поставить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - нарисовать саму анимацию в gif. И периодически двигать блок с этой картинкой по сайту. Естественно когда птичка не нужна - скрывать. Вот примерно список нужного:

- [css visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)
- [css position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)
- [javascript setInterval](http://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=www.w3schools.com&as_q=setinterval)
- [javascript getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)
- [javascript style object left](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_left.asp) и аналогично для top

Comment: пасиб... изучу